# Control fields of views on different pagination

Tags: views

I use pager (as **1** 2 3.. 9 >>Next >>Last) in a views and displaying only 3 articles on one page with the fields title and body.

**I need to hide body of the articles on 3-6 pages.**

**Note:** *It should be done by only using views or views handler but not with css or JS.*

Kindly guide me to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is this:

- In a custom module you implement [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x)

Here's the code:

```
function test_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  // Current page in Views is 0 based.
  $currentPage = $view->query->pager->current_page + 1;

  // Exit early if not in the 'to be modified' page.
  if ($currentPage < 3 || $currentPage > 6) {
    return;
  }

  // Exclude the body from display.
  $view->field['body']->options['exclude'] = TRUE;
}
```